# Loparser to get Number of session by Hour

Tags: iis, iis-6, logparser

how can i use logparser to see how many uniqe session are there by every hour in IIS Logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1144514.aspx) it's not as easy as it seems since Log Parser doesn't support COUNT(DISTINCT), but there is a workaround in post #2.

If you're interested in useful queries there's an old post over at https://serverfault.com/questions/45516/recommended-logparser-queries-for-iis-monitoring which has some useful snippets, you could easily update the unique errors to look for a status code of 200 (although you'd have to filter out your pages only).

Answer (score 0):

By default, your IIS logs will not show session information, just http requests.  You might be able to output session information to your IIS logs but it would depend primarily on what application platform you are running and where you are storing session state.  For example, if you were using .NET, you could use the [AppendToLog method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendtolog%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  You could also look into Custom Logging but it would depend what version of IIS you are running.  Under IIS6 you could implement a [customer logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525189%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  Under IIS7 you can use the [advanced logging extension](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/).

Having no awareness of your platform or tech stack I'm not in a position to say but you could also look in to something like [Elmah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) which Scott Hanselman has blogged a lot on.  If you are running a .NET web app, it seems to have a lot of features already built for you so perhaps that would be an easier route to get your desired goal.